# Dealing with whitespace in grep

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with whitespace in `grep`. How do I tell `grep` to find strings containing whitespace or tabs? The manual tells me nothing. `\s` seems to work for whitespace, and `\S` seems to work for non-whitespace, but it includes all whitespace characters (spaces AND tabs) and it doesn't work if I put it in brackets, treating the backslash and the `\s` as separate characters.

Comment: You'll need to get more clear with your question. Maybe put in an example of data and what you'd expect to match.

Comment: Yes, it isn't entirely clear what you mean.  What would you like to do precisely?  And what does it mean to say that you put "in brackets, treating the backslash and the s as separate characters"?

Comment: "whitespace or tabs"? Tabs *are* whitespace.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure about that?

```
$ printf "a \tb\na b\na\tb" | grep '.\s*.'
a       b
a b
a       b

$ grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.14
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I.e., as shown, `\s` has matched both spaces and tabs -- I included the 'a' and 'b' just to highlight it.

What do you get?

Comment: -1, if I could: `.\s*.` also matches `..`, i.e., any two characters - and since all your strings have two characters, `grep` will match all of them. Should have used `.\s+.`.

Comment: @muru, Please read the question carefully before you doing -1. You've completely missed the point. This is not a question regarding `\s*` or `\s+`. The OP thinks that `\s` is not working, I'm just emphasizing that it is working fine. Secondly, test your result before you post anything. Have you try to run `printf "a \tb\na b\na\tb" | grep '.\s+.'` before you post? Do you know why it is not working? -- you should use `-E` but failed to mentioned that. Next time, please think twice before showing off how kick-ass you are.

Comment: I regret what I said after cooling off. It's been a long and tiring day. Sorry.

Comment: OK, having cooled down, did you spot your mistake? (I can't do a -1, by the way)

Comment: I've double-checked everything before I post and I've made my points clear. End of discussion.

Comment: try `echo ab | grep '.\s*.'` before you end it.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience grep works best with POSIX character classes - look up [[:space:]] for instance.  I use grep extensively in some programs for user input validation and have never had a problem if I stuck to POSIX classes.

However, as commenters have noted, your question is not entirely clear.

Comment: The question was tagged Linux, but just as a heads up, I've had better luck with `[[:space:]]` in Windows CMD; `\s*`; does not seem to work.